# how to run ethereumjs using NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, ethereum

hi everyoune iam trying to work with ethereumjs

problem is i just cant run it by typing 'testrpc'

am getting the msg:

"'testrpc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

any idea why?

thank u

this is my log:

:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>npm install  ethereumjs-testrpc

```
> fsevents@1.1.3 install C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\node_modules\fsevents
> node install


> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\package.json'
npm WARN assignment_2 No description
npm WARN assignment_2 No repository field.
npm WARN assignment_2 No README data
npm WARN assignment_2 No license field.

+ ethereumjs-testrpc@6.0.1
added 368 packages in 31.206s

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\package.json'
npm WARN assignment_2 No description
npm WARN assignment_2 No repository field.
npm WARN assignment_2 No README data
npm WARN assignment_2 No license field.

up to date in 2.663s

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>testrpc
'testrpc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>tgestrpc -p
'tgestrpc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>testrpc
'testrpc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>$ npm install truffle
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2> npm install truffle
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2\package.json'
npm WARN assignment_2 No description
npm WARN assignment_2 No repository field.
npm WARN assignment_2 No README data
npm WARN assignment_2 No license field.

+ truffle@4.0.1
added 55 packages in 9.487s

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>testrpc
'testrpc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>testrpc
'testrpc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\assignment_2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install it globally to run it like this .
Or you can add the directory to your `PATH`:

Right click

My Computer' and go to `Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.`

Double click on PATH under the 'User variables for Username' section, and add

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\testrpc
```

obviously replacing 'username' with yours.

Restart your console window or IDE and you should get a response from the bower command.

Comment: i have added the path 
but still the same result

step 1 C:\Windows\System32> npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc

got response :+ ethereumjs-testrpc@6.0.1
updated 1 package in 19.724s

step 2:

C:\Windows\System32>testrpc
response :

'testrpc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install testrpc globally on your system...

`sudo npm install -g testrpc`